# Changes in Application properties doesn't impact - Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-11

I am using Spring boot 2.5.4. I have written web application. Now i am facing issue with application.properties file variables. If i am changing existing value, In code old value is been read, newly defined object is not coming.

Find the below application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXXXXX:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# Config Variables
ml.url=https://google.com/ml/entities
main.url=https://xxxx.com/staging/mainfile
```

and application config java file

```
@Component
public class ApplicationConfig {
    
    @Value("${ml.url}")
    public String mlurl;

    @Value("${main.url}")
    public String mainurl;

   @PostConstruct
   public void initThat(){
      that = this;
    }
}
```

reading variable in code as

```
@RequestMapping("/readfile")
@RestController
public class AppointmentResource {

private static Logger S_LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger( AppointmentResource.class );

@Autowired
private ApplicationConfig applicationConfig;

@GetMapping(value = "/websiteUrl",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getProduct() {
    String websiteUrl = applicationConfig.mlurl;
    S_LOGGER.info("website url is " + websiteUrl);
    return websiteUrl;
}
}
```

After compiling for few times. Then i changes ml.url to `https://google.com/prod/entities/test`

but in code still i am getting as `https://google.com/ml/entities`.

Can anyone help in getting latest changes from application.properties

I am struck here. Help

Comment: 1) Changes in `application.properties` require Spring application to be redeployed/restarted, recompiling it only isn't enough. 2) If you are accessing your API `/websiteUrl` from browser then it might cache the response and actually don't even hit the endpoint. Try adding some token to the browser URL `/websiteUrl?101010` to prevent caching

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko: Yes i redeployed jar by (mvn clean install) and its doesn't get the latest value from application.properties.

Comment: `mvn clean install` itself will NOT cause redeployment. It only compiles the jar and puts it into Maven repository

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko: Correct me if i am wrong. Normal adding spring-boot-devtools in dependency in pom.xml will recomplie as per my understanding. If not please suggest how to do it.

Comment: disregard my last comment as you didn't mention spring-boot-devtools in your original question

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko: Ok ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. It was picking from the folder config. which i created for different environments